# Transition between phone pages

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone application.

Is there anyway to animate transition between phone pages?

Now, I'm using this to navigate between pages:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SelectComponent.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted because the post contains too much information irrelevant to the question, and too little about the actual question.

Comment: Timwi, your downvote show us that you don't have any idea about windows phone. The same questio, with the same irrelevant question has been asnwered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/f326ef8d-59ba-41f8-b3eb-eacc4f2fc04a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question with answers can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100920205418/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/f326ef8d-59ba-41f8-b3eb-eacc4f2fc04a)

Answer (score 6):

What you could do is have a "Page1Out" storyboard and "Page2In" storyboard. Then, assign a `Completed` event handler to the storyboard like this:

```
Page1Out.Completed += new EventHandler(Page1Out_Completed);
```

Then handle that event

```
void Page1Out_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SelectComponent.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

This will play your out transition and then load the new page. In the new page, you want to do something similar, but handle it in the `OnNavigatedTo()` event.

Hope that helps