# Windows Phone 8: How to animate page navigation?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am new to Win Phone 8 development and after a tiresome unfruitful Googling, I am posting this simple question here:

How to animate page navigation?

Yes, I know how to navigate from one page to another:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But this navigation is instant, and doesn't include any kind of transition. Please help SO!

Comment: 5 views and no answer, is it that difficult folks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transition between phone pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379222/transition-between-phone-pages)

Comment: Hi KooKiz, thanks for pointing out the link. The selected answer there points to another link that says I am not authorized to view the link. The other answer talks about storyboard but doesn't tell how to create storyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the navigational transitions from the toolkit.
http://phone.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 65):

Install the Windows Phone Toolkit using Nuget: https://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit.

In app.xaml.cs:

> RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();

Then, in your page XAML:

> xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

and

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut" />
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut" />
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Comment: as seen on http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide ;)
works for Wp8, too

Comment: This is definitly the better answer, should be THE answer.

Comment: how do I set a duration? its too fast :p

Comment: @Misters: You can download the source code from Codeplex and change them. The storyboards are defined here: http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Transitions/Storyboards