# How To "Upward"/"Downward" Animate Page Navigation?

Tags: windows-phone-8

First and foremost, i am aware that someone asked a [**similar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440133/windows-phone-8-how-to-animate-page-navigation) question previously.

While i am able to successfully animate the page by following this guide [**here**](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide), i am unable to find any information regarding upwards/downwards animation. The animation i am trying to achieve is for my **ApplicationBarIconButton**. If the animation is from right/left, it would be strange.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Xaml I've used with the Windows Phone Toolkit:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideUpFadeIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideUpFadeIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideDownFadeOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideDownFadeOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Other transitions available are:

- Roll
- RotateIn180Clockwise
- RotateIn180CounterClockwise
- RotateIn90Clockwise
- RotateIn90CounterClockwise
- RotateOut180Clockwise
- RotateOut180CounterClockwise
- RotateOut90Clockwise
- RotateOut90CounterClockwise
- SlideDownFadeIn
- SlideDownFadeOut
- SlideLeftFadeIn
- SlideLeftFadeOut
- SlideRightFadeIn
- SlideRightFadeOut
- SlideUpFadeIn
- SlideUpFadeOut
- SwivelBackwardIn
- SwivelBackwardOut
- SwivelForwardIn
- SwivelForwardOut
- SwivelFullScreenIn
- SwivelFullScreenOut
- TurnstileBackwardIn
- TurnstileBackwardOut
- TurnstileForwardIn
- TurnstileForwardOut

If you can't find a transition that gives you the effect you require, just create your own, they're only Xaml Storyboards after all.  If you look at the source code for the Windows Phone Toolkit on CodePlex, you should have all the clues you need.