# Page-turning transitions for Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

How do I get that page turning effect when I swipe left or right inside my app? I've seen it done before, but when reading up on Page Transitions and Storyboard animations, I just don't see how they make it possible. I have not found a single page on MSDN that shows anything *other* than simply changing background color of an element.

Have you done this before, or do you know of any references, samples or have anything you could share?

Comment: Does Pivot fit your needs? You can read about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Chepene I tried the Pivot control template in Vis. Studio and when I flick around it just kind of slides from left to right, - but i don't know how to make it turn (like a page in a book) left or right. But I can use a Pivot style app I just need to figure out how to add that transition effect to it

Comment: Ok, I understand you!
I hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440133/windows-phone-8-how-to-animate-page-navigation/13440336#13440336

Answer (score 6):

There are many navigation transitions effects that you can manipulate if you used Windows Phone Toolkit. It is easy to install it and u can also run the sample and check the transitions to see if one of them satisfy your needs.

http://phone.codeplex.com/

To install it
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit

You should check this also
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/20/windows-phone-toolkit-overview.aspx

Answer (score 6):

**Step1:** Create a Windows Phone 7 application project and add reference to `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll`.

**Step2:** Go to `App.xaml.cs` and set your application's RootFrame property to an instance of TransitionFrame (in `App.InitializePhoneApplication` of the `App.xaml.cs`) if you want to have automatically animated Page transitions:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
    return;

// Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
// screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

// Handle navigation failures
RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

// Ensure we don't initialize again
phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
}
```

**Step3:** Go to your `MainPage.xaml` and  add the "toolkit" prefix declaration

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Comment: Maybe you should credit the source you are copying from: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide