# How to Smoothly Navigate to A Different Pivot Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8, pivot

In a pivot based application, I have added a couple of situations where the user is navigated back to a certain pivot item. However this is done in one sudden movement. Is there a way I can do this action more smoothly, with some form of transition? Or something of the like?

The code I'm trying to use at the moment doesn't seem to work, it navigates to the selected pivot item, but not smoothly...

```
private void pivotTransition(int index)
{
    SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition();
    slideTransition.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideRightFadeIn;
    ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(PivotControl);
    transition.Completed += delegate
    {
        transition.Stop();
    };
    PivotItem pItem = (PivotItem)PivotControl.Items[index];
    PivotControl.SelectedItem = pItem;
    transition.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I animated a panorama item with the same method which worked excellently without any heavy modification...

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment due to reputation points 
but I just tried your code without the slide transistion part using a jump of 2 pivot items

```
private void pivotTransition(int index)
{
var pItem = (PivotItem)DisplayContainer.Items[index];
DisplayContainer.SelectedItem = pItem;
}
```

and the animation sequence was the same as the default sequence which seems fairly smooth to me.

If I have missed something please take a at [this question] ([Windows Phone 8: How to animate page navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440133/windows-phone-8-how-to-animate-page-navigation/13440336#13440336)) as it looks like its using the same tool kit.