# Pivot Item like animation to page

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pivotitem

I am working on Windows Phone 8 app,

i have three pages `A,B and C`.I want to add pivot item like animation to these pages.

I have two buttons in each page `previous and next`, when i click on next button in page A, page A should slide to left and page B should slide from right and vice versa with previous button.

How to do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440133/windows-phone-8-how-to-animate-page-navigation

Comment: I have tried that, but its a different animation

Comment: Is it circular? Can you move from C to A using the next button?

Comment: @ToniPetrina No its not circular, slide from A -> B and the B- > C after that when he clicks on previous button in C page then he will move back to B page

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Pivot` and disable hit detection on it:

and when you want to change a page, simply change the `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: I doubt if it works but still +1 for the clever mind :).

Comment: I will try that, but is there other way that wr can acheive this effect ?Windows app developement lacks APIs , if you compare to Android and iOS.

Comment: Of course there is, but this is the easiest one. You could animate it yourself with storyboards by animating transformations. However, it is a lot of work. I would like to know which API you feel is missing from Windows Phone, could you leave me some feedback in a private conversation?